# Session problem.Why "Continue shopping" does not work?

Tags: asp.net-core, session

I have this view with some product list. List from different table

```
<form method="get">

                <td class="button13"><button type="submit" asp-action="Buy" asp-route-id="@p.ProductId" asp-controller="Search">Buy</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathAndQuery()" />
            </form>
```

Then we go to form post to add some information about client. And then we will go to cart

Controller

```
        public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(new CartIndexViewModel
            {
                Cart = GetCart(),
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            });
        }

        public ActionResult AddToCart(string returnUrl,int priceCart,DateTime dateFromCart, int Tick,int Fli)
        {//we are here after form post


            Cart cart = GetCart();
                cart.AddItem(1,priceCart,dateFromCart);
                SaveCart(cart);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }

 private Cart GetCart()
        {
            Cart cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<Cart>("Cart") ?? new Cart();
            return cart;
        }


        private void SaveCart(Cart cart)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
        }
```

Second View

```
@model Phone1.Models.ViewModels.CartIndexViewModel;

<h2>Your cart</h2>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                <th class="text-right">Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var line in Model.Cart.Lines)
            {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">@line.Quantity</td>
                <td class="text-left">@line.PriceCart</td>
                <td class="text-left">@line.DateFromCart.ToString("D")"</td>


            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="text-right">Total:</td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    @Model.Cart.ComputeTotalValue().ToString("c")
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <div class="text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Model.ReturnUrl"><h3>Continue shopping</h3></a>
    </div>
```

And Infrastructure files

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace Phone1.Infrastructure
{

    public static class SessionExtensions
        {

            public static void SetJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
            {
                session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
            }

            public static T GetJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
            {
                var sessionData = session.GetString(key);
                return sessionData == null
                    ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(sessionData);
            }
        }
    }
```

And other Infrasructure`s file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


namespace Phone1.Infrastructure
{
    public static class UrlExtensions 
    {
        public static string PathAndQuery(this HttpRequest request) =>
                request.QueryString.HasValue
                    ? $"{request.Path}{request.QueryString}"
                    : request.Path.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Startup

```
 public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) =>
         Configuration = configuration;

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.AddDbContext<PhoneAppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:PhoneAppDb:ConnectionString"]));

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddControllersWithViews(mvcOtions =>
            {
                mvcOtions.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            });
            services.AddMvc()
                    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");



                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "",
                  template: "{controller=SearchTicket}/{action=AddToCart}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "",
                template: "{controller=SearchTicket}/{action=Index}/{id?}");



            });



        }
    }
}
```

Model 1

```
namespace Phone1.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class CartIndexViewModel
    {
        public Cart Cart { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Phone1.Models
{
    public class Cart
    {
         private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();

         public virtual void AddItem(int quantity,int priceCart,DateTime dateFromCart)
         {
             CartLine line = lineCollection

                 .FirstOrDefault();

             if (line == null)
             {
                 lineCollection.Add(new CartLine
                 {

                     DateFromCart=dateFromCart,
                     PriceCart=priceCart,


                     Quantity = quantity
                 });
             }
             else
             {
                 //line.Quantity += quantity;
             }


        }

         public virtual void RemoveLine(int priceCart,DateTime dateFromCart) =>
             lineCollection.RemoveAll();

        public virtual int ComputeTotalValue() =>
            lineCollection.Sum(e => e.PriceCart);



        //* e.Quantity
         public virtual void Clear() => lineCollection.Clear();

         public virtual IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines => lineCollection;
     }

     public class CartLine
     {
        public int CartLineId { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateFromCart { get; set; }
        public int PriceCart { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
     }
}
```

All things add to cart, but `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Model.ReturnUrl"><h3>Continue shopping</h3></a>` does not work at all.It does not work even like link `<a>`.What is wrong?

There is no error message.

Controller

```
public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(new CartIndexViewModel
            {
                Cart = GetCart(),
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            });
        }

        public ActionResult AddToCart(string returnUrl,int priceCart,DateTime dateFromCart, int Tick,int Fli)
        {//we are here after form post


            Cart cart = GetCart();
                cart.AddItem(1,priceCart,dateFromCart);
                SaveCart(cart);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }
```

We go to Index method with returnUrl

Comment: What is the value of returnUrl? Which controller action does the link point to? You said that does not work, so, is there any error message on your client side or server side?

Comment: @mj1313 There is no error message.

Comment: @mj1313 There is no error message. I add more information above

Comment: Have you use [F12 Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/log) in your browser to check it?

Comment: @mj1313 I used, it does not show errors and any events when I clicked it